# pyspark split load uniformly across all executors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, mapr

I have a 5 node cluster.I am loading a 100k csv file to a dataframe using pyspark and performing some etl operations and writing the output to a parquet file.
When I load the data frame how can divide the dataset uniformly across all executors os that each executor processes 20k records.

Comment: You can use `repartition(5)`.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, make sure that the input data is split into smaller files.
that way each executor will read and process a single file.

In the case that you can't modify the input files, you can call `df.repartition(5)`, but keep in mind that it will cause an expensive shuffle operation

Comment: Adding repartition is taking longer as you said.I was thinking if the data is evenly distributed across all 5 nodes the process will finish faster.     df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').load("/dwo_poc/rows.csv")
dz=df.repartition(5)
dz.show(100)

Comment: So is it suggested not to repartition.It appears like cost of shuffle is expensive than the benefit of parallelism and evenly distributing the load.Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: There is no one answer that fit all. Best to try and see what works best fit your workload